# laravel 5 fill form select with data

Tags: php, html, forms, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to build a form to assign a reward to an item (I call it a "ticket"). I want a dropdown list with all of the tickets so that the person can then choose.

This is my controller

```
$tickets = Ticket::all();
return view('rewards.create',compact('tickets'));
```

And in my blade.php view

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('ticket','reward for: ') !!}
    {!! Form::select('id', $tickets, Input::old('id')) !!}
</div>
```

This works, but it shows all the fields of the object. I want it show two fields. To store the 'id' in the vallue and 'description' in the written field of the select box, but doing something like

```
{!! Form::select('id', $tickets->description, Input::old('id')) !!}
```

brings up an error.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

The options have to be passed as array: `['value' => 'text']`. You can use `lists()` to build that array for you:

```
$tickets = Ticket::lists('description', 'id');
return view('rewards.create',compact('tickets'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('ticket','reward for: ') !!}
    {!! Form::select('id', $tickets->id, Input::old('id')) !!}
    {!! Form::select('description', $tickets->description, Input::old('description')) !!}
</div>
```